# Exchanging messages between Node.js and Delphi app

Tags: javascript, node.js, delphi, websocket, socket.io

I have 2 apps, 1 large Delphi Windows application and 1 tiny Node.js app. I want the Node.js app to send different messages to the Delphi application depending on input received from a realtime service.

My question is now, how can I start exchanging messages between these 2 apps - how to send messages from Node.js to the Delphi app?

I've been doing some research myself but haven't got any clear answers, although it appears that WebSockets seems to be only solution if I want these messages to be sent in realtime?

I have tried to write some code for my Node.js app using socket.io to give you an idea of what I want:

```
const Realtime = require("ably").Realtime;
const server = require("http").createServer(handler);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

server.listen(80);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Connected!");
    socket.on('event-1', function (data) {
        // alert Delphi app about event
    });
});

const client = new Realtime('XXXXX');

client.connection.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("Realtime connected!");
});

function handler(req, res) {
    console.log("Got em");
}
```

So the idea is the Delphi app starts the Node.js app on boot and all realtime messages received are passed from the Node.js app to Delphi app.

I've been looking at libraries for WebSockets as well for Delphi but only found this https://www.esegece.com/websockets/download, but I've no idea if this is feasible or not.

Hope anyone can give me some advice.

Comment: You could just use their [API](https://www.ably.io/documentation/rest-api) (HTTP + JSON) directly from Delphi as a client (no need for Node.js, I guess).

Comment: There are many different techniques you can use to have two applications communicate. Look for `IPC` or `Interprocess communication`

Comment: That would require polling though right @OndrejKelle?

Comment: @TomBrunberg I will have a look

Comment: @John Good point, I didn't think about it. They offer Javascript (not only Node.js) so you might try embedding a javascript engine in your delphi app and register your callbacks to get notified with messages, to avoid inter-process communication. Otherwise you'll need some form of IPC between the API client process (Node.js, .NET client) and your Delphi process.

Comment: .NET could also be used in-process via interop (unmanaged exports, RemObjects Hydra, COM, etc.) to avoid IPC.

Comment: Yes some form of IPC that is supported on both ends, hmm.

Comment: @OndrejKelle Embedding a JS engine seems like the best solution - will give it an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to send messages from Node.js to the Delphi app?

You can run an embedded HTTP server (Indy TIdHTTPServer for example) in the Delphi application which enables it to receive HTTP requests from the JS application.

Or - if you are more adventurous - you can also design your own protocol and run an embedded TCP server (Indy TIdTCPServer) in the Delphi application.

Besides HTTP, there are other protocols and libraries for message exchange. One which is available for Delphi and nodejs is 0MQ (ZeroMQ):

https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/

Comment: Ended up using this solution, creating a simple local web server turned out to be easy with delphi and node.js integrates very well with web solutions.

Comment: A named pipe would be more lightweight. A full on HTTP server is overkill